# S3 in KNIME: how to get object metadata including last modified date

Tags: amazon-s3, knime

Is there a native KNIME node to read the object metadata of a file in S3?

I need to extract the last modified date of the file from S3.

S3 Connector works fine and am able able to list remote files or download remote files successfully. I have tried also S3 File Picker node and it does not seem to list any metadata.

Alternatively I can do this also in KNIME using a Python Node and AWS boto3 library. But a native KNIME node solution would be preferred for efficiency.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid there is not. We do have a "File Meta Info" node but that only works for local files.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I will go the Python route for now.